# Visual Studio (VC++): take action on warning

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a VS2010 VC++ project. I want to ensure that there are no additional warnings being added with new code. One way I can think of doing this is to store warnings from previous builds on a per file basis and compare them.

To achieve all this, I am looking to see if VS provides any hooks into its build process - some script/action that can be taken on every warning. Is there any such thing?

Comment: Won't the old warnings be pretty outdated as you first fix them, and then as the code evolves the lines they warned about will move around or even be removed? Why not just fix warnings as you get them?

Comment: Just choose the warning level you want and amend your code to remove all warnings completely - then any new ones will show up as you add/change code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I want to stop adding new ones first and then as I fix up old ones, update the compare file

Comment: @RogerRowland There are too many old ones and it is going to take some time to fix them all up. In the meantime, I want to prevent adding new ones...

Comment: Ok, then if you're going to fix them all eventually, it's probably a waste of effort to try to keep comparing. In any case, unless you rebuild, any warnings associated with unchanged code modules won't show up so you'll tend to see new ones anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Selectively disable existing warnings using `#pragma warning(disable, ...)` only if this is absolutely necessary. Then set maximal available warning level + "Treat warnings as errors" turned on.

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : nnnn)

// line that causes warning nnnn

#pragma warning(pop)
```

Finally, fix all warnings disabled by `pragma`. This can take some time, but new warnings will be stopped.